# WebDriverException caused by InterruptedException while running IE Driver tests

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

Currently running a set of test cases written in Java using selenium 2.46

I'd like to run against Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

However, for IE I keep getting  the following stack trace intermittently:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.WebDriverHandler.handle(WebDriverHandler.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpRemoteConfig.handleRequest(JsonHttpRemoteConfig.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
```

Any clues what could be triggering this?

Comment: did you try with selenium 2.44

Comment: Please check the IEDriverServer file , 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Server side settings: selenium-server-2.40.0, iedriver-2.39.0, both 32-bits